Lambda invoke returns an empty payload when doing concurrent invocations
I built several canaries to test my lambdas. They are designed as a fat-lambda approach for simplicity, having a single parameter to define which canary to trigger.
const { isLambda } = require('../helpers/isLambda');
const { authorizerSuccess } = require('./authorizer-success');
const { authorizerFailure } = require('./authorizer-failure');
const log = require('SyntheticsLogger');

exports.handler = async () => {
  const purpose = process.env.CANARY_PURPOSE;
  log.info('Begin canary execution: ', purpose);
  switch (purpose) {
    case 'authorizer-success':
      await authorizerSuccess();
      break;
    case 'authorizer-failure':
      await authorizerFailure();
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown purpose: ${purpose}`);
  }
  log.info('Canary completed successfully');
};

if (!isLambda) {
  exports.handler();
}

Authorize success and fail are pretty simple, they invoke a Lambda that validates the parameter and returns a payload with information about the data validity.
// authorizer-success.js
const { LambdaClient, InvokeCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-lambda');
const { jsonData } = require('../helpers/getVariables');
const log = require('SyntheticsLogger');
const authorizerSuccess = async function () {
  if (!jsonData.authorizer_arn) {
    throw new Error('Authorizer ARN is not defined');
  }
  if (!jsonData.authorizer_payload) {
    throw new Error('Authorizer payload is not defined');
  }

  const invokeParams = {
    FunctionName: jsonData.authorizer_arn,
    Payload: JSON.stringify({ ...jsonData.authorizer_payload }),
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
  };

  const input = new InvokeCommand(invokeParams);
  log.info({ invokeParams });

  const client = new LambdaClient();
  const data = await client.send(input);
  log.info({ data });
  const jsonString = Buffer.from(data.Payload).toString('utf8');

  log.info({ jsonString });
  if (!jsonString || jsonString.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('No response from authorizer');
  }
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

  log.info({ parsedData });
  if (parsedData.statusCode === 403) {
    throw new Error('Login failed, check credentials');
  }
  return 'Authorizer-success canary check successful!';
};

exports.authorizerSuccess = authorizerSuccess;

authorize-fail does the same, just changes the payload to wrong values.
I noticed that when deploying, they execute one after another, but the second one always includes an empty payload on the Lambda response.
// log.info({data})
2024-05-22T19:27:15.283Z    aaaa8d-a0af-4248-843e-3aaaa11b  INFO    {
  data: {
    '$metadata': {
      httpStatusCode: 200,
      requestId: '8aaaad-3408-4caf-90e2-31aaaa7a',
      extendedRequestId: undefined,
      cfId: undefined,
      attempts: 1,
      totalRetryDelay: 0
    },
    ExecutedVersion: '$LATEST',
    Payload: Uint8ArrayBlobAdapter(0) [Uint8Array] [],
    StatusCode: 200
  }
}

However, the logs on the authorizer Lambda correctly include the response Payload.
Timestamps on the authorizer Lambda seem correct: they log the response payload, and around 10ms later I see the response on the 'invoker' Lambda (without the Payload).
I also tried updating the canary switch so that it, for example, calls authorizerSuccess() multiple time concurrently. In this scenario, I invoke the lambda 5 times, and only 2 of them (randomly) get the response payload; the rest get an empty payload response.
The statusCode is always 200.

Discovered that the issue is actually related to AWS-SDK v3 + runtime.SYNTHETICS_NODEJS_PUPPETEER_X_Y (canary runtime for nodejs). I downgraded to v2 and the error is gone.
Found other two cases with similar errors:
Updating aws-sdk v2 to v3 breaks DynamoDB call in Synthetics Canary
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/5892
So I assume this is an AWS bug with no workaround other than downgrading to v2.
